# how to show an element in a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, object

i have an object in javascript. How can i only show "category = "hue" in console.log?

```
let colorlist = {
"colors": [
{
"color": "black",
"category": "hue", // only show this in console.log
"type": "primary",
"code": {
"rgba": [255,255,255,1],
"hex": "#000"
}
},
{
"color": "white",
"category": "value",
"code": {
"rgba": [0,0,0,1],
"hex": "#FFF"
}
},
```

Comment: Loop over the keys in the object and test each for the one you want?

Comment: Can you post a json you want to show in a console.log and how are you going to select it? Otherwise  you can just use console.log ( "'category': 'hue'") code

Comment: If your output is hardcoded, why not just hardcode it? Or do you have some other parameters to determine what needs to be output?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
colorlist.colors.map((item) => {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
        if(value === "hue"){
            console.log(`"${key}" : "${value}"`);
        }
    }
})
```

**The output will be**

```
"category" : "hue"
```